# Fusionmap event click

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I am trying to handle the click event of a map chart which is powered by fusionmap. After a number of tries and it is still not acting as expected.

All I need is very simple, just trigger a function when a country click and know which country got click.

I have been declaring function `FC_Event(DOMId, eventType, objParams){}`, seems like eventType does not listen to click.

Would someone please help and guide me to the right direction.

Comment: Try setting exposeHoverEvent attribute to 1 in <map> element of the XML (or in map Object of the JSON). Also, using FC_Event has been deprecated to capture roll over/out events on entities. The latest version of FusionMaps has EntityRollout and EntityRollover event model. Read more at : [link](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/maps/Contents/javascript/js_event_mouse.html)

Answer (score 1):

The below code may be helpful as an example for using event listener in FMap-

```
function myChartListener(eventObject, argumentsObject)
{    
alert("You are out of entity named: "+ argumentsObject.label);    
}    
FusionCharts("myMapId").addEventListener ("EntityRollover" , myChartListener );
```